Change background color of block to red on the next slide
I am using beamer to make a presentation. I would like the first two of the three blocks in the slide below to change background color to red when I click "Next" after the three blocks have appeared on the slide. The code for the slide can be found below:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{Hypotheses}
\begin{block} 
{}
{\textit{Hypothesis 1}: Example}
\end{block}
\pause
\begin{block} 
{}
{\textit{Hypothesis 2}: Example
}
\end{block}
\pause
\begin{block} 
{}
{\textit{Hypothesis 3}: Example}
\end{block}
}

\end{document}

Thank you for your help!

You can use \only<4->{\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=red!50}} to change the block background colour on specific overlays. To avoid the content from jumping around, I suggest to use white as background colour on the other overlays instead of the default empty colour.
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hypotheses}

\begingroup
  \only<4->{\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=red!50}}
  \begin{block}{}
  \textit{Hypothesis 1}: Example
  \end{block}
  \pause
  \begin{block}{}
  \textit{Hypothesis 2}: Example
  \end{block}
\endgroup
\pause
\begin{block}{}
\textit{Hypothesis 3}: Example
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


